# Volley seems not working after ProGuard obfuscate

Tags: android, obfuscation, proguard

I have an Android app which uses [Google Volley](https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/325304728) as my download broker. I just tried to use ProGuard to obfuscate the code, and find out the volley download starts failing at runtime.

Here's my ProGuard config:

```
-keep class android.support.v4.app.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v4.app.** { *; }
-keep class com.actionbarsherlock.** { *; }
-keep interface com.actionbarsherlock.** { *; }
-keep class com.android.volley.** { *; }
-keep interface com.android.volley.** { *; }

-keepattributes *Annotation*

-dontwarn org.apache.**
```

and here is the error I saw in the code:

```
Async download FAILED. Exception message: The chosen LogFactory implementation does not extend LogFactory. Please check your configuration. (Caused by java.lang.ClassCastException: The application has specified that a custom LogFactory implementation should be used but Class 'org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl' cannot be converted to 'a.a.a.b.c'. Please check the custom implementation. Help can be found @http://commons.apache.org/logging/troubleshooting.html.)
```

I was wondering if I did some proguard config caused some dependency problem. Please help out.

Comment: Did you really write "come.android.volley"? There is a typo at "come".

Comment: @Dalmas oh yeah nice catch. That was a typo. BUT it still did not work after I fixed the typo...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Apache logging library uses some reflection on its log factories. Keeping their names should be sufficient:

```
-keep class org.apache.commons.logging.**
```

Side-note on your configuration: `-keep class .....` always implies `-keep interface .....`, so you can leave out the latter.

Comment: It has not helped me @Eric. Can you please tell me any other solution. I am using STARTAPP SDK also with my app.