# Strange NoClassDefFoundError error when launching a signed release APK with proguard enabled

Tags: android, facebook, proguard, noclassdeffounderror

## **Some Things I have Tried:**

- Removing the Facebook Dependency makes the app not crash anymore but then it only shows a blank white screen. This is with proguard and multidex enabled.
- Upgrading gradle to the latest version doesn't solve anything. I upgraded to gradle 2.0.0-beta4 plugin and gradle 2.10.0.
- Installing a previous version of Android Studio 1.5.1 did not solve anything.
- I have installed Java JDK 1.8 if this is a clue into anything. I can also post some logcat logs to see what is happening.

---

I am using `MultiDex` support in my application with `Proguard` enabled.

Everything works fine when I build a APK file **WITHOUT** proguard enabled and install that on my android phone (I have more than 8 phones so a phone is a non-issue).

When I build a release APK **WITH** proguard enabled it crashes on app startup after i install the app.

I get the following log messages:

```
I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<android.support.v4.app.n>
I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<android.support.v4.app.n>
I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<android.support.v4.app.o>
I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<android.support.v4.app.o>
I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<android.support.v4.app.r>
I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<android.support.v4.app.r>
I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.facebook.FacebookActivity>
I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.facebook.FacebookActivity>
```

And I see the following `RuntimeException`:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.mycustomapp.app, PID: 6814
              java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/facebook/FacebookActivity;
                  at com.facebook.b.aa.c(Validate.java:175)
                  at com.facebook.p.M(FacebookSdk.java:160)
                  at com.mycustomapp.app.utils.a.b.a.<init>(CustomFacebookManagerUtility.java:68)
                  at com.mycustomapp.app.utils.a.b.a.ct(CustomFacebookManagerUtility.java:54)
                  at com.mycustomapp.app.utils.application.MyCustomApplication.onCreate(MyCustomApplication.java:84)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1021)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5990)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:205)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1756)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6895)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
               Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.facebook.FacebookActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.mycustomapp.app-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.mycustomapp.app-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
                  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
                  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
                  at com.facebook.b.aa.c(Validate.java:175) 
                  at com.facebook.p.M(FacebookSdk.java:160) 
                  at com.mycustomapp.app.utils.a.b.a.<init>(CustomFacebookManagerUtility.java:68) 
                  at com.mycustomapp.app.utils.a.b.a.ct(CustomFacebookManagerUtility.java:54) 
                  at com.mycustomapp.app.utils.application.MyCustomApplication.onCreate(MyCustomApplication.java:84) 
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1021) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5990) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:205) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1756) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6895) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199) 
                Suppressed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.facebook.FacebookActivity
                  at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClassNative(Native Method)
                  at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClass(DexFile.java:226)
                  at dalvik.system.DexFile.loadClassBinaryName(DexFile.java:219)
                  at dalvik.system.DexPathList.findClass(DexPathList.java:321)
                  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:54)
                        ... 18 more
                Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.facebook.FacebookActivity
                  at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
                  at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
                  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
                        ... 17 more
               Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

At a loss of what could be causing this issue, but through process of elimination `Proguard` seems to cause some issues.

I looked at the Facebook SDK docs, and they mentioned I don't need any specific proguard rules for their Facebook SDK.

Anybody know how to solve this?

---

EDIT: Adding in the app's `build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
        classpath "com.newrelic.agent.android:agent-gradle-plugin:5.4.0"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
apply plugin: 'newrelic'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor'
        exclude '.readme'
        exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'README.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/MANIFEST.MF'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mycustomapp.app"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 3
        versionName "1.2"

        /**
         * Enabling multidex support.
         */
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets { main { assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets', 'src/main/assets/'] } }

}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile files('libs/gcm.jar')

/**
 * For MultiDex Support
 */
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

/**
 * android support/compatibility libraries.
 */
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.3.0'

/**
 * facebook sdk
 */
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.0'

compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.2.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'
compile 'com.jakewharton:disklrucache:2.0.2'
compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.2@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
compile 'com.amplitude:android-sdk:2.2.0'
compile 'com.appboy:android-sdk-ui:1.11.+'
compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.3'
compile 'com.facebook.conceal:conceal:1.0.1@aar'
compile 'com.newrelic.agent.android:android-agent:5.4.0'

}
```

---

## **Proguard Rules:**

```
# Obfuscation parameters:
#-dontobfuscate
-useuniqueclassmembernames
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
-allowaccessmodification

# Ignore warnings:
#-dontwarn org.mockito.**
#-dontwarn org.junit.**
#-dontwarn com.robotium.**

# Glide
-keep public class * implements com.bumptech.glide.module.GlideModule
-keep public enum com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap.ImageHeaderParser$** {
    **[] $VALUES;
    public *;
}

# Crashlytics
-keep class com.crashlytics.** { *; }
-keep class com.crashlytics.android.**

# Ignore warnings: We are not using DOM model
-dontwarn com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ext.DOMSerializer
# Ignore warnings: https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/FAQs
-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.internal.huc.**
# Ignore warnings: https://github.com/square/okio/issues/60
-dontwarn okio.**
# Ignore warnings: https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/435
-dontwarn com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.**

# Keep GSON stuff
-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }
-keep class com.google.gson.** { *; }

# Keep Jackson stuff
-keep class org.codehaus.** { *; }
-keep class com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.** { *; }

# Butterknife
-keep class butterknife.** { *; }
-dontwarn butterknife.internal.**
-keep class **$$ViewBinder { *; }

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    @butterknife.* <fields>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    @butterknife.* <methods>;
}

# Keep these for GSON and Jackson
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keepattributes EnclosingMethod

# Retrofit 1.X
-keep class com.squareup.okhttp.** { *; }
-keep class retrofit.** { *; }
-keep interface com.squareup.okhttp.** { *; }

-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.**
-dontwarn okio.**
-dontwarn retrofit.**
-dontwarn rx.**

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @retrofit.http.* <methods>;
}

# If in your rest service interface you use methods with Callback argument.
-keepattributes Exceptions

# If your rest service methods throw custom exceptions, because you've defined an ErrorHandler.
-keepattributes Signature

# Joda Time
-dontwarn org.joda.convert.**
-dontwarn org.joda.time.**
-keep class org.joda.time.** { *; }
-keep interface org.joda.time.** { *; }

# Keep Picasso
-keep class com.squareup.picasso.** { *; }
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @com.squareup.picasso.** *;
}
-keepclassmembers class * {
    @com.squareup.picasso.** *;
}

# RenderScript
-keep class android.support.v8.renderscript.** { *; }

# DBFlow
-keep class com.raizlabs.android.dbflow.config.GeneratedDatabaseHolder

# AppBoy
-dontwarn com.amazon.device.messaging.**
-dontwarn bo.app.**
-dontwarn com.appboy.ui.**
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
-keep class bo.app.** { *; }
-keep class com.appboy.** { *; }

# Android Volley
# see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21816643/volley-seems-not-working-after-proguard-obfuscate
-keep class org.apache.commons.logging.** { *; }
```

Comment: Show your build.gradle that demonstrates the config for both builds?

Comment: added in the gradle file for /project/app

Comment: Looks OK to me.  Did you happen to try to add a proguard rule to keep everything in that package?

Comment: Which package? Facebook's documentation doesn't have any proguard settings and they say we don't need it

Comment: Adding the following proguard rule `-keep class com.facebook.** { *; }` doesn't help either.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant by package.  I'm out of ideas unless you wanted to review the process for setting up multidex.  I've not done it myself but I understand it requires changes in a few places.

Comment: This is critical for me since I need to release an update to users.

Comment: Possible that it's related to this issue: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=79826

Comment: updated the question.

Comment: please provide your proguard rules

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### WOW. It was NewRelic and KeepAttributes that was causing issues, adding the following proguard rules solved the issue:

```
# New Relic
-keep class com.newrelic.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.newrelic.**
-keepattributes Exceptions, Signature, InnerClasses
```

Comment: Please can you help me on this question? [NullPointerExcepetion Facebook sdk v4.5.0 when enable Proguard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35380414/nullpointerexcepetion-facebook-sdk-v4-5-0-when-enable-proguard-when-try-to-logi)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is not the best answer but I hope it will help you. as far as the facebook concern when enabling the proguard, yes in the documentation there are no rules for the facebook sdk. 
NOTE : I'm using skd version 4.7.0  `'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.7.0'`. and I have implement this on my project and and got no problem in it. and please try this on your project :

1. use **buildToolsVersion "23"** or latest version **23.0.2**
2. use thid below buildToolsVersion **useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'**
3. try to change your root gradle in the dependencies `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.1'`
   and below I show you my proguard rules and my build.gradle.

hope this can fix your problem.

this is my rules :

```
-keep class butterknife.** { *; }
-dontwarn butterknife.internal.**
-keep class **$$ViewBinder { *; }

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    @butterknife.* <fields>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    @butterknife.* <methods>;
}

-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.**

#
# Twitter library - start
#

-dontwarn twitter4j.**
-keep class twitter4j.** { *; }

#
# Twitter library - end
#

# adcolony start
-dontwarn com.immersion.**
-dontnote com.immersion.**
-dontwarn android.webkit.**
#adcolony end

#app billing
-keep class com.android.vending.billing.**
#end app billing
```

and this is my build.gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "antiboring.game"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 11
        versionName "1.9.0"


        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                    'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor'
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

    sourceSets {
        androidTest {
            java.srcDirs = ['androidTest/java']
        }
        main { java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'src/androidTest/java'] }
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }
}




repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    // App dependencies
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0'
    //unit testing
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.4.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.4.1'

    //apps library
    compile files('libs/twitter4j-core-4.0.2.jar')
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['adcolony.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.balysv.materialmenu:material-menu-toolbar:1.5.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'

    //social media
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.7.0'

    //animation
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.daimajia.easing:library:1.0.1@aar'
    compile 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:1.1.3@aar'

}
```

Comment: Fixing the facebook issue doesn't resolve anything it's a dex issue. Did you read the updated question?

Comment: yup, but it looks like our problem is way ahead of me. can't figure it out why unless you can try to delete the library one by one. or you can try my suggestion above. and I know this probelm is pain in the ass

Comment: yea it's an art issue

Comment: I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.mycustomapp.app.views.activities.MainActivity>