# Android app crash with proguard-rules

Tags: android, encryption, proguard, obfuscation, android-proguard

My application works fine without applying pro-guard-rules but for security purpose I have to apply pro-guard-rules in my application .
I got these errors when I apply rules and trying to run my application.

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                    Process: com.nearely.nearelysales, PID: 4275
                                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.nearely.nearelysales/com.nearely.nearelysales.activities.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
                                                                        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                        at com.nearely.nearelysales.activities.MainActivity.k(Unknown Source)
                                                                        at com.nearely.nearelysales.activities.MainActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
                                                                        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is my progurd-rules file :

> proguard-rules.pro

```
-injars      libs
-outjars     bin/classes-processed.jar
# -libraryjars C:\dev\android-sdk\platforms\android-23\android.jar

-dontpreverify
-repackageclasses ''
-allowaccessmodification
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic
-keepattributes *Annotation*

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider

-keep public class * extends android.view.View {
    public <init>(android.content.Context);
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
    public void set*(...);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers class * extends android.content.Context {
   public void *(android.view.View);
   public void *(android.view.MenuItem);
}

-keepclassmembers class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    static ** CREATOR;
}

-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
    public static <fields>;
}

-keepclassmembers class * {
    @android.webkit.JavascriptInterface <methods>;
}

-dontwarn butterknife.internal.**
-keep class **$$ViewInjector { *; }
-keepnames class * { @butterknife.InjectView *;}

-keep class javax.ws.rs.** { *; }
-dontwarn org.immutables.gson.**

-dontwarn android.test.**
-dontwarn org.junit.**
```

Comment: It is clear from your log that the crash happened in `MainActivity`. Make sure you have added pro guard exclusions for all libraries you are using. Check whether you have excluded the libraries you use in your MainActivity

Comment: @MuchOverflow I used only Volley library in MainActivity .so what should I exclude ? can you give me suggestion ?

Comment: check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21816643/volley-seems-not-working-after-proguard-obfuscate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like you have used volley and that crashed your application with proguard .
you can write this line to your **proGuard**.

```
-keep class org.apache.commons.logging.**
```

Answer (score 0):

After Setting Proguard Enabled in your Application , all the Proguard custom rules depends on whether you have set Proguard enabled at apps initial stage or middle or later .

1. Initial

> It Means that if you integrate any third party library in your app , the rules gets set by its own if the library provides or supports proguard.

2.Middle and Later

> In Middle if you set up proguard in your app and you have already integrated many third party libraries , it means that every library is integrated without rules. Then at that you need to setup custom rules in your proguard-rules.pro file.

There are many scenarios the app crashing depends.one is that your Pojo classes or model classes that you are using is obfuscated by proguard, so you need to set rules in proguard-rules.pro file
like:

```
-keep class * {
     public private *;
}
```

or in other ways use below code as per the requirement

```
-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.**
-ignorewarnings
-keep class * {
    public private *;
}

-keep class com.google.android.gms.* { *; }
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**

-dontwarn org.xmlpull.v1.**
-dontnote org.xmlpull.v1.**
-keep class org.xmlpull.* { *; }

#retRofit
# Platform calls Class.forName on types which do not exist on Android to determine platform.
-dontnote retrofit2.Platform
# Platform used when running on RoboVM on iOS. Will not be used at runtime.
-dontnote retrofit2.Platform$IOS$MainThreadExecutor
# Platform used when running on Java 8 VMs. Will not be used at runtime.
-dontwarn retrofit2.Platform$Java8
# Retain generic type information for use by reflection by converters and adapters.
-keepattributes Signature
# Retain declared checked exceptions for use by a Proxy instance.
-keepattributes Exceptions
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @retrofit2.http.* <methods>;
}
# Orm
-keep class * extends com.raizlabs.android.dbflow.config.DatabaseHolder.* { *; }
-keepclassmembers class * {
    native <methods>;
}
-dontwarn okio.**
-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.**
-dontwarn okhttp3.**
-dontwarn javax.annotation.**
-dontwarn com.android.volley.toolbox.**

# com.github.siyamed:android-shape-imageview
-dontwarn android.support.v7.**
-keepattributes *Annotation,Signature
-dontwarn com.github.siyamed.**
-keep class com.github.siyamed.shapeimageview.*{ *; }
-dontwarn org.xmlpull.v1.**
-dontwarn uk.co.senab.photoview.**

#Image Cropper
-keep class androidx.appcompat.widget.* { *; }



# Keep source file names, line numbers, and Parse class/method names for easier debugging
 -keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
 -keepnames class com.parse.* { *; }


 # Required for Parse
 -keepattributes *Annotation*
 -keepattributes Signature
 -dontwarn com.squareup.**
 -dontwarn okio.**


-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
-keep class com.parse.*{ *; }
-dontwarn com.parse.**
-dontwarn com.squareup.picasso.**
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}
```